# How to use SQL query to manipulate Excel data?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to perform a group by SQL statement within an excel file. Below is the excel table. How can I execute a simple group by SQL statement via VBA to get the results.

[image]

The end result would be something like below,

[image]

PS - I do not want to use methods like Pivot, Power query etc. I need to do it using VBA and SQL within the excel file.

Example 02 -

I found below simple example,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45720915/5002322

I tried to replicate this so I can use the same method for my issue and get the feel of it.

Using example 02

Here I created a new excel file named "Book11.xlsx" and saved it.

I added values into "Sheet2" as A1 = 1, A2 = 2 and A3 = 3.

Created a excel Macro and used below code.

```
Public Sub OverkillSum()

    Dim connection As Object
    Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

    Dim recordset As Object
    Set recordset = connection.Execute("SELECT SUM(Values) As Total FROM [Sheet2$]")

    Sheet1.Range("A4").Value = recordset.Fields("Total").Value
    recordset.Close
    connection.Close

End Sub
```

When I ran the macro I get an error saying
*"No value given for one or more required parameters"*

My excel file sheets

[image]

Comment: You can't use SQL to query Excel spreadsheets from within Excel. Use PowerQuery instead. Arguably, PowerQuery is better than SQL, it just takes some getting-used-to. It's also the first GUI editor for building queries that actually _isn't terrible_ (anyone else remember `MSQUERY`?)

Comment: Thanks. I was reading that we may be able to do it using  ADODB.Connection but I'm not understanding it. I want to automate the group by function. I was trying to record the macro to use power query but seems it is not integrated in that way. Can we automate it using Power Query ?

Comment: Yes, it is possibe via [ADODB](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-copy/#Using_ADO_and_SQL). What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Storax I tried to go through this simple example to see if it works 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45720915/5002322

Here I created a new excel file named "Book11.xlsx" and saved it.
I added values into "Sheet2" as A1 = 1, A2 = 2 and A3 = 3. 

Created a excel Macro and copy past the code in there. When I ran the macro
I get an error saying "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Comment: Please edit your post accordingly

Comment: @Storax could you check please. I have added it to my main question

Comment: You have to add a header to your excel file and the header name has to be `Value` otherwise `SELECT SUM(Values) As Total FROM [Sheet2$]` does not know what column to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the code to run you have to add a header to the column A, i.e your sheet should look like that

[image]

This is stated in the connection information with `HDR=Yes` and the name `Values` of the column is used in the SQL staement `SELECT SUM(Values) As Total FROM [Sheet2$]`

Updated code for using the [sheetname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481428/6600940) instead of the codename when writing the result

```
Public Sub OverkillSum()

    Dim connection As Object
    Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

    Dim recordset As Object
    Set recordset = connection.Execute("SELECT SUM(Values) As Total FROM [Sheet2$]")

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = recordset.Fields("Total").Value
    recordset.Close
    connection.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done the suggested change. I can run it now without any errors. However, I don't see the out put in cell Sheet1!A4. Would you be able to help me here as well please.

Comment: Hmm, for me the code is working as expected. Output is on **Sheet1** in cell A4, it is not on **Sheet2** !

Comment: I closed down all the opened sheets and tried again. I get an error at 


Sheet1.Range("A4").Value = recordset.Fields("Total").Value

Error says - 
Run-time error '424'
Object Required

Comment: Yes, you have to have sheet with the codename Sheet1.

Comment: I do have it as sheet1. I just attached a screenshot to the question. If you could check please.

Comment: Perfect thanks. It works now. I will try to build it for my initial issue. Hoping to get some help if I run into further issues.

Comment: The SQL Statement for your first example is  `"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4, Sum(Qty) as SumQty FROM [Sheet3$] GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4"` PS I was to lazy to write the column names completely ;-)